# Creating Global Picklist using GlobalValueSet of MetadataService API through APEX

Tags: apex, metadata-api, global-picklist, create

I am executing below code in Dev Console.Code is executing without any error, but Global picklist is not getting created.

any suggestion?

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

String valueSetName = 'test123';

MetadataService.GlobalValueSet globalValueSet = new MetadataService.GlobalValueSet();


MetadataService.CustomValue newItem = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
  newItem.fullName = 'value';
  newItem.label = 'label';
  newItem.isActive = true;
  newItem.default_x = true;

if(globalValueSet.customValue ==null){
 globalValueSet.customValue = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();
}    

globalValueSet.customValue.add(newItem);

globalValueSet.masterLabel='test123';
globalValueSet.sorted=false;
globalValueSet.description='sd';
service.createMetadata(
                new MetadataService.Metadata[]{
                        globalValueSet
                });
```

and Response of saveResult is,

errors = null and success = false